# How do I create a custom button in VSCode Source Control tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a VSCode extension. I want to add a custom button to the Source Control View which when clicked will run my extension.

Such like these buttons:
[image]

How would I do this or are there any resources/tutorials which can explain more? As I've looked everywhere online and can't find anything.

Comment: does the API mention a menu entry for this location, if not you can add a feature request to the VSC repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the repo's of other VSCode extensions that contain icons in the Source Control tab. Looks like the only thing you need are these 2 objects in the `package.json`.

```
"contributes": {
  "commands": [ ... ],
  "configuration": { ... },
  "menus": {
    "scm/title": [
      {
        "when": "scmProvider == git",
        "command": "myExtension.command", // This was the only thing I edited
        "group": "navigation"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```